# Can't find ISS position data API that uses the https protocol

Tags: iss, coordinates

I have used the [open-notify API to track the ISS](http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json) in a script I've written. It's just excellent, but it doesn't use the secure version of the http protocol. Now I find myself trying to include it on my website, only to find out that - duh - I need an https source since the server uses https.
Does anyone know a free API that gives out kind of the same data (longitude and latitude of the ISS) in real time using the https protocol? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Code to compute these directly is available in almost every programming language, search for "SGP + language".  This link has implementations in a few languages: http://celestrak.org/software/vallado-sw.php

Answer (score 6):

I found this one here:
https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544

You can get position of all satelites include ISS. ISS number is 25544

Comment: Maybe you should add a little more body to this answer. When you have at least 15 reputation you'll be able to comment.

Comment: @TheRocketfan this is actually a fine answer for the question.  There isn't really more to include--that's the link to an example of an API that returns requests on HTTPS, and the link is pointed to return information about the ISS.  If the link breaks, the API is gone.  There isn't deeper information to pull from the source and quote here.

Comment: @ Erin Anne Okay, thanks for letting me know